# Java - Get new points of rotation in Graphics2D

Tags: java, rotation, 2d, rendering, collision

I need to get new points of rotation to know the true position and dimension of the object, for a example:

[Example 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlEKd.png).

The context of my application is rendering 2D graphics, the main for it below:

```
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        ...

        g2d.rotate(Test.angle * Math.PI / 180, Test.hero, Test.heroY); 
        g2d.drawImage(Main.hero, Test.hero - 15, Test.heroY - 15, this);
        ...
```

The image is drawn correctly, but I cannot get the new points.

Comment: Hello north-american guys, I discovered a cool solution, then after I'll post examples here. Thank you anyway.

Comment: But i still continue open for others answers, remembering.

Comment: I'm developing the solution and results are very good at moment but certainly will need improvements.

Comment: Please don't close this thread, as I already said, I developed satisfactory result, however I will post an organized response, is better than generic algorithms, and in spare time I'll post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double angle = ang * Math.PI / 180;
double sin = Math.sin(angle);
double cos = Math.cos(angle);       

double a = (centerX + ray) - x0;
double b = centerY - y0;
int xx = (int) (a * cos - b * -sin + x0);
int yy = (int) (a * -sin + b * cos + y0);

ang++;
```

it will rotate a point around centerX and centerY in a +ray from these origins, the code has tested and works from all angles.